# How to enable a user to save an image to my android gallery app straight from their browser

Tags: android

On an android phone, if you hold down on an image while in a browser, a dialog pops up asking you if you want to save the image. If saved, the image is downloaded straight to your gallery. If I wanted the user to save images to my app as conveniently as they are saved to their gallery from the browser, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if you hold down on an image while in a browser

There are many Web browser apps for Android, just as there are many Web browsers for desktop operating systems.

> a dialog pops up asking you if you want to save the image

Not all browsers for Android necessarily offer this. Those that do may do so in different ways.

> If saved, the image is downloaded straight to your gallery.

There is no such concept in Android. A "gallery" is an app, not a place where images are stored. The downloaded image may appear in a gallery app, but it is not downloaded "to" the gallery. At most, it is downloaded to a file somewhere.

Also note that not all browsers necessarily support this.

> If I wanted the user to save images to my app as conveniently as they are saved to their gallery from the browser, how would I go about doing that?

With the current Firefox for Android, "Save Image" is handled internally by the browser, downloading the file to the `Downloads/` directory on external storage. Firefox for Android does offer a "Share Image" option. To show up in the list of available share destinations, try implementing an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`, offering to handle `file` and `content` `Uri` schemes and a MIME type of `image/*`.

With the current Chrome for Android, "Save Image" also appears to be handled internally by the browser, or possibly via `DownloadManager`, also putting it in the `Downloads/` directory. There does not appear to be a way to alter this behavior. Chrome does not appear to offer a "share" option.

And there are many other browsers. Whether they provide hooks for you to handle the downloads would be up to those browser developers.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. so if an android user uses chrome, they'd have to first save the image, and then from `Downloads/`, share the image?

Comment: @thebeest: On Android 4.4+, you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, and the user could browse to `Downloads/` and pick the image. This is roughly equivalent to the "file open" dialogs that you see in desktop operating systems. On older devices, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` may allow you to do the same thing, though it is not guaranteed that some app will be on the device that will offer the user to browse `Downloads/`. Or, as you suggest, you could offer some activity (`ACTION_VIEW`, `ACTION_SEND`, `ACTION_EDIT`, etc.) that the user might be able to start up via a file manager, gallery app, etc.

Comment: "you could offer some activity that the user might be able to start up via a file manager" but i can't change the file manager activity, as far as what buttons the user could see when they select a file and what they can do, so it seems like my only option is to create an intent that would respond to the user selecting a file and clicking the share button that appears on selection; because it seems like that's the only button the user could click in that activity that would scan for intents